# python: os.system does not execute shell command

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, graphviz

I need to execute shell command in python program (I have ubuntu). More specifically I want to create graph using graphviz in python script. My code is

```
os.system("dot -Tpng graph.dot -o graph.png")
```

It does not work, but if I just type "dot -Tpng graph.dot -o graph.png" in command line then everything is fine. Do you know what the problem? Thank you!

Edit: does not work means that nothing happens, there are no errors.

Output from  "dot -v -Tpng graph.dot -o graph.png"

```
dot - graphviz version 2.26.3 (20100126.1600)
```

Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_pango.so.6
Using textlayout: textlayout:cairo
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_dot_layout.so.6
Using layout: dot:dot_layout
Using render: cairo:cairo
Using device: png:cairo:cairo
The plugin configuration file:
    /usr/lib/graphviz/config6
        was successfully loaded.
    render  :  cairo dot fig gd map ps svg tk vml vrml xdot
    layout  :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
    textlayout  :  textlayout
    device  :  canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps fig gd gd2 gif gv imap         imap_np ismap jpe jpeg jpg pdf plain plain-ext png ps ps2 svg svgz tk vml vmlz vrml wbmp x11 xdot xlib
    loadimage   :  (lib) eps gd gd2 gif jpe jpeg jpg png ps svg

Comment: Care to elaborate what "It does not work" means?  Please provide the full traceback of any errors.

Comment: What is the output of `os.system('/usr/bin/which dot')`?

Comment: Then `dot` is on your path, now try `os.system('dot -v -Tpng graph.dot -o graph.png')` (that is, use `-v` for verbose).

Comment: @EmilioSilva it does not create file graph.png ( if I type in terminal this command then it creates graph.png)

Comment: @capoluca, the `-v` option is to see if `dot` gives some explanation as to why it does not create it.

Comment: @EmilioSilva ok. but I cannot understand what is wrong from output

Comment: My guess is that the output file *is* created, but in a different location than you expect.  Try to pass the full path as parameter.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I tried it, passed the full path, but nothing happens :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I should close file graph.dot before executing the command.